# Can't see Nexus One as a USB drive when connecting to Windows 7

Tags: 2.2-froyo, nexus-one, usb-connection-mode

I've connected my N1 to my Windows 7, and I don't see it as a USB drive. I don't see any message on the phone that allows me to enable this (in the past, I used to see a notification about the phone being connected, that allowed me to enable it as a USB drive. Now I don't)

What should I do to access the files?

Answer (score 1):

Under 'Settings' there should be an option 'Connect to PC'. From here you can change the connection type or get the phone to ask you each time it plugs in. (Apparently this is an HTC Sense specific setting(?) so not as relevant here). edit: [an answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6238/cannot-access-local-storage-on-htc-desire-hd-with-linux/6257#6257) has directions to the USB settings.

If it is still not working after changing the settings it may be worth trying another USB cable. Are you sure the cable is working ok? Does the phone indicate that it is charging when it is plugged in to the PC? The cable needs to be capable of data transfer (some will only supply power for charging). Also, the USB port needs to be USB 2.0, not 1.0 or 1.1

If you are sure the cable is working and the phone is still not recognised this might be a Windows problem perhaps. Try re-installing the device driver by 'uninstalling' the phone in Device Manager (see link below for details):

[Info in answer from this post here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=105e782793e2fb75&hl=en)

Comment: There is no 'Connect to PC under' settings. The cable is charing, so it's working well at least in this regard.

Comment: Hmm, that could be a Sense specific setting then I guess.

Comment: This post on the Google support forum has some info that may be relevant: 

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=105e782793e2fb75&hl=en 

tl;dr - your USB port needs to be USB 2 (1 or 1.1 only allows charging) and your cable needs to be rated for data transfer (some will only allow charging). Failing that it could be a Windows 7 issue - uninstall the driver from Device Manager then re-connect the phone (better instructions on that link).

Comment: I agree with Martin, sounds like a cable or possibly USB port (either computer or device) issue.

Comment: Oh, and rather than `Settings -> Connect to PC` try looking for `Settings -> Applications -> USB settings`