# Cannot access local storage on HTC Desire HD with Linux

Tags: htc-desire-hd, linux

If I set my new HTC Desire HD to connect to PC in disk drive mode, a Windows computer can see the internal storage as a Removable Disk. If I attempt the same with my Linux system, "HTC Android Phone" briefly shows up, but is not possible to interact with and disappears a few moments later.

How do I use my HTC Desire HD from my Linux system?

(It does not currently have a microSD card - that is in the mail atm)

Comment: Did you install drivers or a software package on Windows?

Comment: ...and can you access any other USB drives from your Linux system?

Comment: If it doesn't have a microSD, what are you trying to do when connecting it to the Linux system. Also, which distro are you running?

Comment: Err, I am an idiot - my phone network actually provided me with a 2GB SD card which will do as a temporary measure until the 16GB one arrives, rendering this question irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Have you switched Mass Storage mode on? Not sure about Desire HD, but it should be either in USB Settings under `Settings -> About Phone -> USB Settings`, `Settings -> Wireless and network -> USB Settings`, or it may show up directly in the notification bar when USB is connected.

If this doesn't help, do a `lsusb` after connecting the phone and check it's detected.