# How do I disable the popup when I connect my phone to my PC via USB?

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications, usb-connection-mode

How do I disable the popup (the one asking me if I want to mount my SD card) when I connect my phone to my PC via USB?

I've been told it's a feature of CyanogenMod but I can't for the life of me find it. I'm using CyanogenMod 7.0 RC, with Android 2.3.2.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @pideltajah, Is your device rooted? Also check if you ar able to access USB storage option from your device.

Comment: Adding a screen shot would help. The original question is for Android 2.3.2 and you are on 6.0. You can include the screen shot in comments

Comment: My device is not rooted. Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/OK5W1MC

Comment: Remove the PIN access to remove the dialog. It's a security thing.

Answer (score 6):

If you enable USB debugging in the Developer options, the phone's "USB Connected!" screen doesn't popup anymore :)

Comment: That depends on the phone...

Comment: Does not help. That's what I did a long time ago.

Answer (score 4):

Not a CyanogenMod user, but have you checked under `Settings -> About Phone -> USB Settings`, or `Settings -> Wireless and network -> USB Settings`?

Comment: Additionally, `Settings -> Applications -> USB Settings`.  Some phones really have it under Wireless?  Weird.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was weird, but some do according to this answer (I guess it might be to do with USB tethering?): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6238/cannot-access-local-storage-on-htc-desire-hd-with-linux/6257#6257

Comment: I think in CyanogenMod, it is under Settings -> Applications -> Development. But it has been a long time since I've had a device that supported CM... I wish I could run CM.

Comment: I've already gone through every setting I can find, with no luck. "Settings -> About Phone -> USB Settings" doesn't exist, "Settings -> Wireless and network -> USB Settings" doesn't exist, and "Settings -> Applications -> USB Settings" doesn't exist. "Settings -> Applications -> Development" only has the following options: USB debugging, stay awake, allow mock locations, stop app via long press, device hostname.

Comment: This is probably something that they will remove then as I don't remember it in previous versions of CM. After they started working with the gingerbread sources from AOSP, they have not yet merged in all the previous modifications, like removing that popup.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly looks like, Google has disabled USB Mass storage option for most recent Android versions as you probably have noticed,
do not allow you to mount SD Card / storage partition as USB Mass Storage (UMS)
when plugging it to a computer.

Given that you are rooted, you can try the following resoltuions:

1. **Using terminal to mount mass storage**

su

```
setprop persist.sys.usb.config mass_storage,adb
reboot
```

If you want to go back to MTP, open terminal emulator and enter:

```
su
setprop persist.sys.usb.config mtp,adb
reboot
```

su
setprop sys.usb.config mtp,adb
reboot

2. **Activate auto-mount when USB debugging is enabled**.

As previously mentioned, when USB debugging is enabled the sd card will automatically mount when connected to the computer provided the drivers were installed correctly.

Thus you will not get persistent notifications about sd card monting

3. **Using QtADB**

QtADB is a full-featured tool (designed for windows )and has a plethora of features to manage your droid. Some of these include:

- File manager (copying files and dirs between phone and computer, delete , creation of dirs)
- App manager (installing, removing, creating backs ups etc)
- Shell and  more..

The essence of this is that it alows **mounting of external sd card to a computer without giving annoying notifications**. Check here for more info: [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/)

4. **Using USB MASS STORAGE Enabler (root)**

This is one of the  few apps offering to restore the lost Universal Mass Storage (UMS) option.

1. After downloading the [tool](https://iwf1.com/how-to-mount-android-device-as-usb-mass-storage-ums/) ,connect your device using USB cable to your computer.
2. Open the ‘UMS Enabler’ app and press ‘Enable Mass Storage’. Remember,  give the app root access if it asks.

At this point, you might get various messages by the app, for instance, there a message asking you to set **SELinux** – a Linux module Android uses to make it more secure – to permissive state; this is required for the app to run properly

Credits

1. [Any way to get USB Mass Storage instead of MTP?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2023066)
2. [How To Mount Android Device As USB Mass Storage (UMS)?](https://iwf1.com/how-to-mount-android-device-as-usb-mass-storage-ums/)
3. [QtADB  for android](https://qtadb.wordpress.com/features/)

Comment: "As previously when USB debugging is enabled the sd cardd will automatically mount when connected to the computer provided the drivers were installed correctly."

Maybe for some devices but for me, this is incorrect. I have debugging enabled and can easily mount but still get annoying notification pop ups every single time I plug in.

Comment: @pideltajah really? I reckon this is something to do with android version, because I never get any of these notification (android 4.3). Let me look into it

Comment: Yes. I noticed someone previously mentioned this but I guess it just depends on the particular device. Thank you! Also, I added a comment to the OP question with a link to a screen shot. I'm not sure how a screen shot would be helpful but @beeshyams seemed to think that it might be.

Comment: I just perfomed the tests now. I inserted USB and switched to USB Storage option, there was **no notification** and when I use PC mode (HiSuite) it tuns with USB debugging enabled and again **no notifications** and if I **disable USB debugging** it automatically goes to Charging mode with **no notifications**) I will perfom again with another android 6 device (samsung) I will let you know the results

Comment: @pideltajah: **update** Tested today with Samsung Note 4 (android 6), I don't seem to see your described notification, even with USB debugging diasabled. **Only difference with and 4.3 is that only options are MTP and Camera**, I am beginning to feel it might be security featured locked in your particular ROM, otherwise I have no conclusive facts other than these ones.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I think I will ask a new question about this specifically for my device and Android version.

Comment: @pideltajah That's okay

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable all notifications that pop up when you connect your USB cable go to the "menu" then "notifications" then touch "usb connection" then change the settings to "Charge only"

Comment: It doesn't change this behavior. Plus I still want the MTP to work. I just don't want to be asked about it.

Answer (score 0):

Developer Options -> Default USB configuration -> Charge phone only (or whatever you want as default), then it will not pop up again.

Answer (score -2):

It's usually under Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging

Comment: I'm talking about the dialog that appears asking me if I want to mount my SD card, which is unrelated to USB debugging.